# Prove that every prime number divides some number in the sequence $ a_n = 2^n+3^n+6^n-1 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

Let $ (a_n) $ be a sequence of numbers such that for all natural numbers $ n $:

$$ a_n = 2^n+3^n+6^n-1 $$

Show that every prime number divides some number in that sequence.

Comment: I trust you have made some effort to solve this on your own. Please show this in your question, including what you've had difficulty with. Thanks.

Comment: This is IMO 2005, Problem 4. By the way, I can't see any reason as to why it is closed.

Comment: Also, is really seems quite weird that some problems are closed while they really look alright, and those which are missing details remain open... It seems it is highly stochastic, and that, it depends on whoever is reviewing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $p$ be prime number. Consider $a_{p-2}=2^{p-2}+3^{p-2}+6^{p-2}-1$. Then
    \begin{align*}
6a_{p-2} & \equiv 6(2^{p-2}+3^{p-2}+6^{p-2})-6 \pmod{p}\\
& \equiv 3\cdot 2^{p-1}+2\cdot 3^{p-1}+6^{p-1}-6\pmod{p}\\
& \equiv 3+2+1 -6\pmod{p}\\
& \equiv 0 \pmod{p}.
\end{align*}

For $p>3$, we will have $\gcd(6,p)=1$. So we can multiply by $6^{-1}$ on both sides to get
$$a_{p-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

Now you can deal with $p=2,3$ as special case.

Comment: Intuitively, taking $n=-1$ would give $a_{-1} = \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac16 - 1 = 0$, and the remainders mod $p$ should repeat every $p-1$ steps, so taking $n=p-2$ also works. This isn't quite rigorous, but it's motivation for considering $a_{p-2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I had to look up how to justify that all these powers were congruent to 1 (mod.p). Indeed Fermats little theorem solves this problem fast. Thanks for help and for such quick response.